# Type of logarithm in Jenson-Shannon and Bhattacharyya distance

Tags: distance, distance-functions, bhattacharyya

Both Jenson-Shannon and Bhattacharyya distance can be used to measure the similarity of two probability distributions.

Bhattacharyya distance between two distributions $p$ and $q$ is defined as $D_B(p,q)=-\log\left(\int{\sqrt{p(x)q(x)}dx}\right)$, where usually the natural logarithm $\ln$ is used as the log function.

The Jenson-Shannon distance is calculated as the square root of the Jenson-Shannon divergence as $D_{JS}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2} P(\log(P)-\log(M))+\frac{1}{2} Q(\log(Q)-\log(M))}$, where the binary logrithm is used in many implementations.

When using both distance measures in parallel, which type of logarithm should be used in either case?

Comment: It doesn't matter--all logarithms are the same up to a scale factor determined by the base of the logarithm.  Note, though, that the two distances you give use different units (one is in terms of logarithms and the other in terms of square roots of logarithms), so it would be meaningless to compare them to each other.

Comment: @whuber: do you want to post your comment(s) as an answer? [Better to have a short answer than no answer at all.](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5326/1352) Anyone who has a better answer can post it.

Comment: @Stephen I posted those remarks as a comment because they don't answer the question.